# Backups from MySQL slave server -- Good idea or bad?

Tags: mysql-replication, database-backup, master-slave

I'm have one MySQL master and two MySQL slaves set up to replicate.  I'm running my database backup process, consisting of an `Xtrabakup` (via the perl wrapper `Innobackupex`) backup and an atomic `mysqldump`, off one of the slaves.  This morning, I noticed the slave I do the backup from had stopped replicating a few days ago, meaning my backups were out of sync with the master.

Should I be backing up from the master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should be monitoring your slaves so that you know when they stop replicating, and can fix it.

Comment: Not too detailed. You may write a few rows about binlog expirity and possibilities to monitor replicas

Comment: I have found this handy python script to e-mail me when things go wrong http://geert.vanderkelen.org/post/678/